# Unable to connect my projector via USB-to-RS232

Tags: windows-7, usb, projector, rs232

I have to connect a Mitsubishi projector XL6600U via a USB-to-RS232 connector. I have a Prolific PL2303 cable, the drivers are available here: http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=225&pcid=41

Although I installed the drivers for my Windows 7 64 bit, I get the following screenshot:

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Since that Projector has DVI, USB, Serial, and Ethernet connections, why are you attempting to use the Serial connection? (Just curious).  Also, that Prolific cable, according to the page you linked, could have issues depending on the chip version.  Have you tried removing the drivers, and allowing Windows update to detect and install them (as is suggested by the page)?

Comment: @BonGart Yes, I have tried removing the drivers and letting Windows do its job. Mitsubishi has supplied a utility tool that reads the information about how long the projector was used, etc. This works with serial port *only*.

Comment: @BonGart please tell me more about the chip version issue ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild - The information on the problem is on the page you linked to.  Are you 100% this is an actual Prolific.  Fake Prolific cables present this EXACT issue.  Furthermore which version of the able do you have `PL-2303HXA` or `PL-2303XA`.  If you have installed the drivers from that page the cable should work, if it doesn't and based on the information on the page, you have purchase a ounterfeit cable.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah it looked like it. I am going to have to buy another one :)